# Send a List to other Page (apex and visualforce)

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, selectoption

***The idea:***

- Do a search, and shows a List with Select Option
- Select some items and send it to a new Page (just those witch I selected)

***The problem:***

- In the new page, is showing all the searched list with all item(selecteds and the others). I don't know what to do anymore.

***Here is my code:***

APEX CODE

```
public class wSearchP2 {

public wSearchP2() {

}


public Product2 p2 {get; set;} 
public boolean selected {get; set;}
public List<wSearchP2> searchs {get; set;} 
public List<Product2> selectedProducts {get; set;} 
public string keyword;


public wSearchP2(Product2 p2) {
    this.p2 = p2;
    selected = false;
    }
public void setKeyword(string keyword){
    this.keyword = keyword;
}
public string getKeyword(){
    return this.keyword;
}

public List<wSearchP2> getSearchs(){
    if(searchs == null){
        searchs = new List<wSearchP2>();
        for (Product2 p2 :Database.query('SELECT Id, Name,Codigo__c,Marca__c FROM Product2 WHERE Name Like :keyword OR Name Like \'%' + keyword + '%\'')){
            searchs.add(new wSearchP2(p2));
        }
    }
    return searchs;
}

public List<Product2> processSelectedProducts() {
  selectedProducts = new List<Product2>();
  for (wSearchP2 p2 :getSearchs()) {
      if (p2.selected == true) {
          selectedProducts.add(p2.p2);
      }
  }
    return selectedProducts;
}
 public PageReference getPage2() {
  processSelectedProducts();
  return Page.vAgoraVai;
}

public PageReference search_now() {
    getSearchs();
    return null;
}

}
```

VISUALFORCE CODE

```
<apex:page controller="wSearchP2">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedProducts}" var="produto">
            <apex:column >
             <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!produto.selected}" />
             <apex:outputLabel value="{!produto.p2.name}" /> 
             <apex:outputLabel value="{!produto.p2.Codigo__c}" /> 
             <apex:outputLabel value="{!produto.p2.Marca__c}" /> 
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

And the NEW PAGE

```
<apex:page controller="wSearchP2">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:inputText value="{!keyword}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search_now}" />
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!searchs}" var="produto">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!produto.p2.name}" /> 
       <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!produto.selected}" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
     <apex:commandButton action="{!getPage2}" value="go"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: `selectedProducts`  is a Product sObject list then How are you using it as wrapper list? confirm you are going from New page to VISUALFORCE CODE page.

Comment: FYI, using the same class for your controller and for the wrapper makes your code harder to follow. You can add a nested class to the controller class to use as the wrapper.

Comment: you could use same controller for both the pages and use the data seamlessly..

Answer (score 0):

In your method. Use `setRedirect(false)` to get the same values in different page

```
public PageReference getPage2() {
  processSelectedProducts();
  PageReference pr =  Page.vAgoraVai;
   pr.setRedirect(false);
   return pr;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work too , it's showing all the items